# Alternative to nesting enums

Tags: c#, enums

I'm trying to create several `enums` as such, that gives the syntax of `Dropdown.Category.Subcategory`. However, I have been reading that this isn't such a good idea. My choice for this was mostly because I couldn't think of any other way to select different `enum` values depending on the choice of the category, and then the choice of the subcategory is subject to the selected `enum` based on the `enum` values.

Is there a better way to create such functionality? I would prefer to be able to easily identify both the `.Category` and `.Subcategory` names, and it would be a bonus if this code was readable.

Just to make it clear, I want to be able to choose the `Category`, then have an appropriate `Subcategory` selection.

```
public class Dropdown
{
    public enum Gifts
    {
        GreetingCards,
        VideoGreetings,
        UnusualGifts,
        ArtsAndCrafts,
        HandmadeJewelry,
        GiftsforGeeks,
        PostcardsFrom,
        RecycledCrafts,
        Other
    }
    public enum GraphicsAndDesign 
    {
        CartoonsAndCaricatures,
        LogoDesign,
        Illustration,
        EbookCoversAndPackages,
        WebDesignAndUI,
        PhotographyAndPhotoshopping,
        PresentationDesign,
        FlyersAndBrochures,
        BusinessCards,
        BannersAndHeaders,
        Architecture,
        LandingPages,
        Other
    }
}
```

Comment: What were you reading, and why did it say that this wasn't a good idea?  In most cases enums shouldn't be nested in classes; they should be at a top level, but this seems like an appropriate enough context.  In most cases though it's just annoying to access an enum through it's parent type all the time.  If it's beneficial in a certain context, then that's fine.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a database instead?

Comment: If those enums are only used within the Dropdown class, there's no reason not to do what you are currently doing.

Comment: @Scott There was several reasons given by StackOverflow users, one of them being that nesting in classes isn't a good idea. I'm just curious for alternatives. A database seems a bit overkill...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class that cannot be inherited from externally, give it several inner classes, each extending from it.  Then add static read only variables for each of the values that you want to represent:

```
public class Dropdown
{
    private string value;

    //prevent external inheritance
    private Dropdown(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public class Gifts : Dropdown
    {
        //prevent external inheritance
        private Gifts(string value) : base(value) { }

        public static readonly Dropdown GreetingCards =
            new Gifts("GreetingCards");
        public static readonly Dropdown VideoGreetings =
            new Gifts("VideoGreetings");
        public static readonly Dropdown UnusualGifts =
            new Gifts("UnusualGifts");
        public static readonly Dropdown ArtsAndCrafts =
            new Gifts("ArtsAndCrafts");
    }
    public class GraphicsAndDesign : Dropdown
    {
        //prevent external inheritance
        private GraphicsAndDesign(string value) : base(value) { }

        public static readonly Dropdown CartoonsAndCaricatures =
            new GraphicsAndDesign("CartoonsAndCaricatures");
        public static readonly Dropdown LogoDesign =
            new GraphicsAndDesign("LogoDesign");
        public static readonly Dropdown Illustration =
            new GraphicsAndDesign("Illustration");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

In this case every single value is actually an instance of type `Dropdown`, so you could have, say, a parameter to a method that accepts a `Dropdown` instance.  With enums there is no way to say, "I want to accept any of the enums declared in the `Dropdown` class."

Here is some example usage:

```
public static void UseDropdown(Dropdown type)
{
    if (type is Dropdown.Gifts)
    {
        if (type == Dropdown.Gifts.GreetingCards)
        {
            DoStuff();

        }
    }
    else if (type is Dropdown.GraphicsAndDesign)
    {
    }
}
```

You could also have a parameter that accepts an object of type `Gifts` or `GraphicsAndDesign`, if you only want a sub-type to be valid in some context.

Sadly, using this solution there's no good way to `switch` on a dropdown value; you have to just use `if`/`else if` chains to check the values.

The use of an instance string value may not be required (see the first revision for a version without it) but it can be very helpful to be able to have a meaningful string value (or other kind of value; you can associate an integer, a byte, or whatever with each enumeration value).

The `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations should be meaningful if left without being overridden.

You can implement `IComparable` if the items should be logically ordered somehow, like real enums.

Comment: Much better solution than mine +1.  I'm thinking about deleting mine ;-(

Comment: Have to say, that's really elegant too. Thank you so much, I prefer this!

Comment: Small problem, this syntax is valid code, because of the inheritance to `Dropdown`: `Dropdown.Gifts.GraphicsAndDesign.Gifts.GraphicsAndDesign`, etc.