# Choose enum based on previously chosen enum value

Tags: c#, enums

Here's the problem I have. Take these `enum` objects in `public class Item`:

```
public enum Category {
    FirstCategory,
    SecondCategory,
    ThirdCategory
}
```

Once the `enum` value is selected, I would like to use it to then find the subcategory, inside another `enum` with the value name:

```
public enum FirstCategory {
    FirstCategoryA,
    FirstCategoryB,
    FirstCategoryC
}
```

I would like to be able to set two properties, `Category` and `Subcategory`, from these values, but most of all I would like a simple syntactical way to firstly set `Item.Category`, and from the value selected choose which `enum` the `Item.Subcategory` can be selected from, something like this (pseudo code):

```
Item item = new Item();
item.Category = Item.Category.FirstCategory; 
item.Subcategory = // enum for subcategory choices based on item.Category value
```

**Notes:** Doesn't have to work at all like this. Any other suggestions for a better way to select one value from a collection, then base the collection for the subcategory based on this.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to nesting enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547833/alternative-to-nesting-enums) @Nick, how is this different than the question you posted previously?

Comment: You already marked [Servy's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19548179/2145211) as solving your issue

Comment: I really want to be able to choose the `enum` based on the name of the `Category` choice, perhaps I was narrow-sighted about being able to do this with Servy's answer. The main difference is the syntax; I don't really want the syntax `Item.Category.Subcategory`, I would prefer `Item.Category`, then base the possible selections of `Item.Subcategory` on it's selection - that's what's I'm having trouble with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change the enums to be represented by a single class

```
public class Category
{
  public string CategoryName {get; set;}
  public List<Category> SubCategories {get; set;}
}
```

Then use it something like this:

```
  var availableCategories = new List<Category>
            {
                new Category
                    {
                        CategoryName = "FirstCategory",
                        SubCategories = new List<Category>()
                            {
                                new Category {CategoryName = "FirstCategoryA"},
                                new Category {CategoryName = "FirstCategoryB"},
                                new Category {CategoryName = "FirstCategoryC"}
                            }
                    },
                new Category
                    {
                        CategoryName = "SecondCategory",
                        SubCategories = new List<Category>()
                            {
                                new Category {CategoryName = "SecondCategoryA"},
                                new Category {CategoryName = "SecondCategoryB"},
                                new Category {CategoryName = "SecondCategoryC"}
                            }
                    }
            };

        var availableCategoryNames = availableCategories.Select(a => a.CategoryName);
        var selectedCategory = availableCategoryNames.First();
        var availableSubCategories = availableCategories.Where(a => a.CategoryName == selectedCategory)
                                                        .SelectMany(c => c.SubCategories)
                                                        .Select(s => s.CategoryName);
```

Obviously you'd want to change how you select your category, but this should give you a general idea.

You can populate your Categories however you want- hardcode (yuck), some resource file (meh), or stored in a DB somewhere (my preference, if reasonable).  Also, if you ever need "sub-subcategories" you've already got the plumbing in place.

If you want, you can make your Category class `sealed` as well, so it cannot be inherited.